# QML: Extract information from repeater

Tags: qt, qml

In the snippet of code below I'm displaying a variable number of TextEdit items, each one being in a Rectangle which is the delegate of a repeater.  When I hit the 'Play' button, the slot for that will need to collect the player names and call a Q_INVOKABLE method (not shown) to pass that data to the C++ backend.  For the purposes of this question I'm just trying to display the player names in the onClicked slot of the Play button but am not sure how.  I left '???' where I am trying to figure out how to retrieve information inside the rectangle of each delegate instance.

At this point I'm open to a solution to this approach or just being told that I'm approaching this the wrong way.  I'm really pretty new to the QML side of Qt.

Thanks

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {
    id: root
    property int playerCount: playerCountSelect.currentValue

    RowLayout {
        id: layout
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 5
        spacing: 6
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Label {
            text: "Enter number of players"
        }

        ComboBox {
            id: playerCountSelect
            model: [2, 3, 4]
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        id: mainRow
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        spacing: 6

        RoundButton {
            text: "Play"
            width: 40
            radius: 2
            font.pointSize: 12
            onClicked: {
                for (var i =0; i < playerList.count; i++) {
                    console.log(playerList.itemAt(i).???)
                }
            }
        }

        Column {
            spacing: 6
            Repeater {
                id: playerList
                model: root.playerCount

                Rectangle {
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    width: 120
                    height: 32

                    TextEdit {
                        font.pointSize: 12
                        text: "Player " + (index+1) + " name"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        RoundButton {
            text: "Quit"
            width: 40
            radius: 2
            font.pointSize: 12
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to expose the property you want in the Repeater's delegate.

```
            Repeater {
                id: playerList
                model: root.playerCount

                Rectangle {
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    width: 120
                    height: 32

                    // Expose the player name
                    property alias playerName: textField.text

                    TextEdit {
                        id: textField
                        font.pointSize: 12
                        text: "Player " + (index+1) + " name"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then you can access that property in your print statement by doing this:

```
console.log(playerList.itemAt(i).playerName)
```